# How to transform string into pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this string

"id=IAfpK, val=58, id=WNVdi, val=64, id=jp9zt, val=47"

. I want to create a pandas data frame out of it. Any ideas how to do so?

Comment: `import pandas as pd`
`string = "id=IAfpK, val=58, id=WNVdi, val=64, id=jp9zt, val=47"`
`df = pd.DataFrame({'String' : [string]})`
`df`

Comment: @DavidErickson i want a dataframe with two columns and of length 3 as there are 3 key, val pairs

Comment: makes sense. These details should be in your question if you can modify it and make it clear exactly what you want.

Comment: @DavidErickson If there is no duplicate why to vote to close it !

Comment: I retracted my vote, since it is not as simple as the code I copy and pasted above after you have explained it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = "id=IAfpK, val=58, id=WNVdi, val=64, id=jp9zt, val=47"

data = [*map(lambda x: x.split('='), data.split(', '))]
ids = [*filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'id', data)]
vals = [*filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'val', data)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    data={
        'id': [*map(lambda x: x[1], ids)],
        'val': [*map(lambda x: x[1], vals)]
    }
)
```

Comment: Useful only for a very short data and is just unnecessarily complex.  Not everything has to be a `map()`, `lambda` or `filter()`. Use it where necessary/useful and always use `timeit` when using too many of them. In my experience it's harder to read and worse code overall (but has its uses). Instead: ```>>> def better(data):
...     from collections import defaultdict as ddict
...     out = ddict(list)
...     data = [it.split("=") for it in [item.strip() for item in data.split(",")]]
...     for key, val in data:
...         out[key].append(val)
...     return out```

Comment: Sorry, the comments can't format it properly. Just add a newline on each `...`.